# R: Matrix counting matches when 2 teams interacted from schedule with 3 participants per match

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I'd like to make some calculations on FIRST robotics teams and need to build, for lack of better words, a binary interaction matrix.  That is when two teams were on the same alliance.  Each alliance has three teams, so there are 7 values from each match added to the matrix, when considering (i,j), (j,i), and (i,i).

The full data I'm using is here: http://frc-events.firstinspires.org/2016/MOKC/qualifications

But for simplicity, here is an example of 9 teams playing 1 match each.

```
> data.frame(Team.1=1:3,Team.2=4:6,Team.3=7:9)
  Team.1 Team.2 Team.3
1      1      4      7
2      2      5      8
3      3      6      9
```

The matrix should count each binary interaction, (1,4),(4,7),(3,6),(6,3),(9,9), etc, and will be an N x N matrix, where in the above example N=9.  Here's the matrix that represents the above lists:

```
> matrix(data=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,+
+ 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,+
+ 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,+
+ 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,+
+ 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,+
+ 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,+
+ 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,+
+ 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,+
+ 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),9,9)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
 [4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
 [7,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

In the real data, the team number are not sequential, and are would be more like 5732,1345,3451,etc, and there are more matches per team meaning the matrix values would be between 0 and max number of matches any of the teams played.  This can be seen in the real data.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: could you maybe elaborate on what the rows and columns of your matrix mean? I'm interpreting as 'team 1 has met team 4 and 7 one time`. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.  From the match schedule 1,4, and 7 were together, and so that gives adds one to (1,1), (1,4), (4,7), (1,7), (4,1), (7,4) and (7,1) in the matrix, where you have (row,column).

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more elegant approach, but here is one using data.table.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(Team.1=1:3,Team.2=4:6,Team.3=7:9)

#add match ID
dat[,match:=1:.N]
#turn to long
mdat <- melt(dat,id="match",value.name="team")[,variable:=NULL]

#merge with itself
dat2 <- merge(mdat, mdat, by=c("match"),all=T, allow.cartesian = T)

# reshape
dcast(dat2, team.x~team.y, fun.agg=length)

   team.x 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1:      1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
2:      2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
3:      3 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
4:      4 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
5:      5 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
6:      6 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
7:      7 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
8:      8 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
9:      9 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

And, because I can, one in base-R. A case where I think the use of a for-loop is justified (as you keep modifying the same object).

```
#make matrix to put results in

nteams = length(unique(unlist(dat)))
res <- matrix(0,nrow=nteams, ncol=nteams)


#split data by row, generate combinations for each row and add to matrix
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  x=unlist(dat[i,])
  coords=as.matrix(expand.grid(x,x))
  res[coords] <- res[coords]+1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion with base functions. I tried to create a matrix. My approach was to look for the position indexes for 1.

```
library(magrittr)

mydf <- data.frame(Team.1 = 1:3, Team.2 = 4:6,Team.3 = 7:9)

### Create a matrix with position indexes

lapply(1:nrow(mydf), function(x){

       a <- t(combn(mydf[x, ], 2)) # Get some combination
       b <- a[, 2:1] # Get other combination by reversing columns
       foo <- rbind(a, b)
       foo

     }) %>%
do.call(rbind, .) -> ana

ana <- matrix(unlist(ana), nrow = nrow(ana))


### Another set: Get indexes for self (e.g., (1,1), (2,2), (3,3))

foo <- rep(1:max(mydf), times = 2)
matrix(foo, nrow = length(foo) / 2) -> bob


### A matric with all position indexes
cammy <- rbind(ana, bob)


### Create a plain matrix
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = max(mydf), ncol = max(mydf))

### Fill in the matrix with 1
mat[cammy] <- 1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
# [6,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [7,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
# [8,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
# [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

EDIT

Here is a revised version based on the previous idea. This is not concise like Heroka's idea with base functions. In my modified data, team 1 and 4 had two matches. The idea here is that I counted how many times each pair appeared in the data set. The dplyr part is doing that. In the for loop, I filled in the matrix, mat by going through each row of `cammy`.

```
mydf <- data.frame(Team.1=c(1:3,1),Team.2=c(4:6,4),Team.3=c(7:9,5))


#  Team.1 Team.2 Team.3
#1      1      4      7
#2      2      5      8
#3      3      6      9
#4      1      4      5

library(dplyr)

lapply(1:nrow(mydf), function(x){

       a <- t(combn(mydf[x, ], 2)) # Get some combination
       b <- a[, 2:1] # Get other combination by reversing columns
       foo <- rbind(a, b)
       foo

     }) %>%
do.call(rbind, .) -> ana

ana <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(ana), nrow = nrow(ana)))


### Another set: Get indexes for self (e.g., (1,1), (2,2), (3,3))
foo <- rep(1:max(mydf), times = 2)
data.frame(matrix(foo, nrow = length(foo) / 2)) -> bob


cammy <- bind_rows(ana, bob) %>%
         group_by(X1, X2) %>%
         mutate(total = n()) %>%
         as.matrix


### Create a plain matrix
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = max(mydf), ncol = max(mydf))



for(i in 1:nrow(cammy)){

    mat[cammy[i, 1], cammy[i, 2]] <- cammy[i, 3]
}

print(mat)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    1    0    0    2    1    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    2    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0
# [5,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    1    0
# [6,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [7,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
# [8,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
# [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

Comment: Nice. But how would this work if a team appears multiple times? (Like in OP's description)

Comment: @Heroka Thanks for your comment. I need to think about this point.

Comment: @Heroka I did what I could do. My idea is not concise like yours. But I tried to exploit my original idea and added more to address the issue. Here time to go to bed now. If you can give me any advice to improve my idea, that would help me.